# DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR еще нужен?

Tags: php, файлы

Хотелось бы обсудить этот вопрос. Кто не знает, это такая штука которая учитывает в путях к файлам слеш в зависимости от ОС. Но я как-то не особо понимаю зачем возиться с этим, если php вроде как под виндовс прекрасно понимает где файл и без этой свистопляски. Точнее я попробовал и без проблем.

Comment: пути с <b>/</b> нормально работают как под линем так и под виндой так что, уже - не актуально... Да и вы же сами попробовали, терзают смутные сомненья? :)

Comment: Да нет, просто критиковали тут люди мою систему, я пишу уже строго под 5.3, поглядываю на 5,4. А пока пишется использую первую свою версию. Ну вот и не охота возиться. Хотя многие далее продолжают тыкать пальцем.

Comment: AlexWindHope очень даже прав! путь есть путь и как он лежит тот или иной php или asp или... скрипт полнотью не волнует!

Comment: В таком случае всех кто будет тыкать пальцем буду отправлять сюда. Будете им объяснять :)

Comment: Реально трудно представить какую-нибудь новую ОС, у которой сепаратор будет отличаться от '/'. По сути Винда сдалась, API через .dll поддерживает '/'. 

Так что, стройте себе на здоровье, пути через '/'.

Comment: хоть в чем-то Билл & company уступили ^^

Answer (score 3):

Я тут через 4 года случайно проходил мимо...

Да, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR **ещё нужен**.
Вдруг вам потребуется часть пути файла. Как вы его получите?

```
explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, realpath(__FILE__)).
```

Потому как

```
explode("/", realpath(__FILE__))
```

- в Windows не сработает так, как надо.
  (Да да, я знаю про **pathinfo()**)

Так же я думаю для многих систем нужна функция isWindows(), её можно написать так:

```
function isWindows()
{
    return DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR === "\\";
}
```